# Loss Fluctuates with YOLOv4-tiny on a 1,700 big dataset with 16 classes

Tags: python, object-detection, yolo, image-augmentation, yolov4

I am building a logo detection system using YOLOv4-tiny. I've built a custom synthetic dataset where I've drawn transparent logos on top of gameplay screens. The logos, before drawn on the background, were augmented (blurring, perspective transformation, resizing, rotating, etc). Here are some examples of the sort of data that I have.

[image]
[image]

I am pasting between 1-5 logos (randomly) on defined positions on the background image for 1,700 images. Each logo is a class and I have 16 classes. When I run this with YOLOv4-tiny, this is an example of my output. My loss fluctuates and I don't understand why.

```
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 37 Avg (IOU: 0.281087), count: 1, class_loss = 0.738789, iou_loss = 15.317201, total_loss = 16.055990 
 total_bbox = 485600, rewritten_bbox = 1.175453 % 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 30 Avg (IOU: 0.547854), count: 5, class_loss = 4.434289, iou_loss = 2.494116, total_loss = 6.928406 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 37 Avg (IOU: 0.767385), count: 1, class_loss = 1.036910, iou_loss = 0.562877, total_loss = 1.599788 
 total_bbox = 485606, rewritten_bbox = 1.175439 % 

 (next mAP calculation at 3147 iterations) 
 Last accuracy mAP@0.5 = 3.82 %, best = 3.82 % 
 3038: 2.917786, 2.895705 avg loss, 0.002610 rate, 2.421050 seconds, 145824 images, 42.306447 hours left
Loaded: 1.968205 seconds - performance bottleneck on CPU or Disk HDD/SSD
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 30 Avg (IOU: 0.602211), count: 3, class_loss = 2.421113, iou_loss = 0.208666, total_loss = 2.629779 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 37 Avg (IOU: 0.000000), count: 1, class_loss = 0.000067, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 0.000067 
 total_bbox = 485609, rewritten_bbox = 1.175431 % 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 30 Avg (IOU: 0.583863), count: 4, class_loss = 3.290887, iou_loss = 0.876662, total_loss = 4.167549 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 37 Avg (IOU: 0.383844), count: 1, class_loss = 0.823941, iou_loss = 8.962539, total_loss = 9.786480 
 total_bbox = 485614, rewritten_bbox = 1.175419 % 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 30 Avg (IOU: 0.566122), count: 11, class_loss = 9.910147, iou_loss = 1.705420, total_loss = 11.615566 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 37 Avg (IOU: 0.000000), count: 1, class_loss = 0.000120, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 0.000120 
 total_bbox = 485625, rewritten_bbox = 1.175393 % 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 30 Avg (IOU: 0.582394), count: 5, class_loss = 3.849459, iou_loss = 0.561072, total_loss = 4.410531 
v3 (iou loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.07, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 37 Avg (IOU: 0.365837), count: 1, class_loss = 0.918538, iou_loss = 6.407685, total_loss = 7.326223
```

My question is, what is a takeaway from this? I haven't even tested the model against a test set to see how well it is performing. Do I need to improve the augmentation of the logos? How can I make sense of this output?

**Update**
This is the performance of the model. It correctly detected what logo it was but totally messed up on the bounding box.
[image]

Comment: Did you try training with -mAP flag?

Comment: @A.Parico Yes I did. Also, check the edits. I updated it with an output from the model.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You pasted the logos randomly but are there equal number of objects per class across the dataset?

Comment: @A.Parico What do you mean?

Comment: For example, for all your 1700 images, for logo 1, there are  total of100 bounding boxes. For logo 2, there are total of 130 bounding boxes, and so on. In this case, there's imbalance in the data.

Comment: I have about 4873 screenshots. For every logo, I select a batch of 50 random screenshots, paste that logo in addition to up to 4 more logos. So every screenshot will have its specific logo but it might have another one, or 2 more or 3 more.

Comment: Okay. Let's say you have Logo 1 and Logo 2. How many times did you paste Logo 1 show in your 1700 labeled images? How about Logo 2? The number of their instances in your dataset should be ideally equal. If not, that can cause problems but there are ways to address this.

Comment: 50x for each logo

Comment: Also. The IOU is consistently stuck at 0.07 from the beginning of the training to the end. How do I make sense of this?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228289/discussion-between-a-parico-and-oo92).